# Opportunity Products Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I added custom action to create new record for opportunity products, added on page layout.
I can see in full site. BUT not in Salesforce1.

Answer (score 1):

The action created has to be added to publisher layout not on to the page layout.You will need to drop the action onto the publisher layout where you can find other actions.

see the below link for more details

[Salesforce1 - Page Layouts and publisher actions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21856/salesforce1-page-layouts-and-publisher-actions)

Comment: Thanks Mohith,I added the action to publisher action on Opportunity pagelayout. I can see that on full salesforce site (in feed section on top), but not in Salesforce1.

Comment: sounds weird .Might be a bug .Try raising a case with SFDC and see if they help you to sort it out

Comment: It is working fine in Winter 15 release. Thanks